# How to get the command line for AZCopy?

Tags: powershell, azcopy

I want to send dump files to a storage container and for the copy to work we need to obtain a SAS key for the container we’re copying to.

When you use Azure Storage Explorer you can copy a file to a container and then copy the command it used to the clipboard which looks something like this:

$env:AZCOPY_CRED_TYPE = "Anonymous";
./azcopy.exe copy "C:\temp\test.txt" "https://dbbackups.blob.core.windows.net/memorydumps/test.txt?{SAS-TOKEN}" --overwrite=prompt --from-to=LocalBlob --blob-type Detect --follow-symlinks --put-md5 --follow-symlinks --recursive;
$env:AZCOPY_CRED_TYPE = "";

I copied this from AZ Storage Explorer when copying a file called test.txt from c:\temp to the memorydumps container in a Storage Account.

What I would need help with is creating a PowerShell script that generates the above command line so I can run it on azcopy-less nodes and have the dumps end up in the storage container. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Azure PowerShell equivalent to upload blobs to your container. The [Set-AzStorageBlobContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-5.8.0) uploads a local file to an Azure Storage blob.

```
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File "C:\Temp\test.txt" `
  -Container $containerName `
  -Blob "Image001.jpg" `
  -Context $ctx
```

Refer to this blog post for a detailed walkthough: [File Transfers to Azure Blob Storage Using Azure PowerShell](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/azure-cvo-blg-how-to-upload-files-to-azure-blob-storage#H_H2)